# Set div width in TD in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, sencha-touch

I am using sencha touch xTemplate. As we all know, the sencha touch xtemplate is just html.  And I would like to use a div inside a td for following reasons:

1. Use text-overflow:ellipsis to cut the text.
2. I tried display the text in , then the text-overflow won't work in IOS Safari.

My code is like this:

```
......
......
'<td>' +
    '<div style = "overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; width:80%; max-width: 100%;">'+  
     'Here is the text to cut'+
    '</div>'+
'</td>' +
......
......
```

Here is a problem:
When I put the div inside the td, the td expands. It doesn't expand when I set max-width to a number like 100px. But I don't want to set width to be a fixed number. How can I make the div and td not expand?

I am still junior in this area. So please please help me!

Comment: Just share the html output, or use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 3):

`width:80%;max-width:100%` makes no sense. If the width is `80%`, it can never reach the maximum you've set for it. At least one of `width` or `max-width` should be an absolute value, not a percentage.

As far as the `<td>` expanding goes, you could try setting a width on the table cell. If that doesn't work, you can also add `table-layout:fixed` to the table's styles.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try the table-layout later. But I need to set a percentage value because the application is designed for mobile phone. The width of table always changes.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the max-width, and try setting a `white-space: nowrap;` css on the `td` element.

Does this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/YeDjG/2/

Comment: The nowrap attribute of `<td>` is deprecated in HTML 4.01. Use `<td style="white-space: nowrap">` instead

Comment: Thank you. But the example doesn't work when I set the width as XX%, which is very important to me. It only work when I set the width as XX px. I will try to give an example on jsfiddle later.

Comment: hmm, i couldn't test for safari now, but it works on chrome http://jsfiddle.net/YeDjG/3/

Comment: @user1413305 : What way did you use?